# How to make Behat wait for an AJAX call?

Tags: php, ajax, bdd, behat

Scenario: Modify and save an incomplete change to a Campaign

```
Given I click on the Campaign section folder
And I press Save in the selected Campaign
Then I should see an error balloon informing the changes cannot be saved
```

Point is that this 'error balloon' in the final step is a ajax call which will then bring a green or red balloon according to the success of the operation. Currently what I do is after 
'And I press Save...' I will do a sleep(3) to give it time for this balloon to show up. This doesn't seem very smart coz you are wasting time and also because some times it can take more or less time for this call to be processed.

How do you guys make your behat tests wait for Ajax do be done instead of just putting the beasts to sleep?

thank you very much for any feedback!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is done by waiting for your outstanding ajax calls to hit 0. jQuery.active will check just that for you.

In your FeatureContext.php, you can do something like;

```
public function iShouldSeeAnErrorBalloon($title)
{
    $time = 5000; // time should be in milliseconds
    $this->getSession()->wait($time, '(0 === jQuery.active)');
    // asserts below
}
```

And do make sure you use a Mink Driver that runs javascript and ajax (the default does not).

Answer (score 2):

I do it by waiting for the DOM to change as a result of the Ajax Call. I made a subclass of DocumentElement, calling it AsyncDocumentElement and overriding the findAll method:

```
public function findAll($selector, $locator, $waitms=5000)
{
    $xpath = $this->getSession()->getSelectorsHandler()->selectorToXpath($selector, $locator);

    // add parent xpath before element selector
    if (0 === strpos($xpath, '/')) {
        $xpath = $this->getXpath().$xpath;
    } else {
        $xpath = $this->getXpath().'/'.$xpath;
    }

    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();

    // my code to wait until the xpath expression provides an element
    if ($waitms && !($this->getSession()->getDriver() instanceof \Behat\Symfony2Extension\Driver\KernelDriver)) {
        $templ = 'document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null ).snapshotLength > 0;';

        $waitJs = sprintf($templ, $xpath);

        $this->getSession()->wait($waitms, $waitJs);
    }

    return $this->getSession()->getDriver()->find($xpath);
}
```

Then in \Behat\Mink\Session I changed the constructor to use that class.

```
public function __construct(DriverInterface $driver, SelectorsHandler $selectorsHandler = null)
{
    $driver->setSession($this);

    if (null === $selectorsHandler) {
        $selectorsHandler = new SelectorsHandler();
    }

    $this->driver           = $driver;
    $this->page             = new AsyncDocumentElement($this);
    $this->selectorsHandler = $selectorsHandler;
}
```

Once I did this, I found my AngularJS tests were working.  So far, I've only tested in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Prototypejs (e.g Magento), the equivalent code is:

```
public function iShouldSeeAnErrorBalloon($title)
{
    $this->getSession()->wait($duration, '(0 === Ajax.activeRequestCount)');
    // asserts below
}
```

Comment: where is the $duration variable comming from?

Comment: http://mink.behat.org/api/behat/mink/session.html#wait()


`public void wait(integer time, string condition)
Waits some time or until JS condition turns true.`

Comment: Just updating that link, though as I've used line numbers it'll no doubt be out of date soon: https://github.com/Behat/Mink/blob/master/src/Behat/Mink/Session.php#L318-L329