# Behat\Mink: wait($timeout) does not work

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, mink

I'm using `Mink` together with the **Zombie Driver** to write acceptance Tests. Now I'm trying to make an **ajax call**, so I'm using the `wait($timeout)` method to wait for the response, but it does not work. I'm calling wait like `$this->session->wait(20000)`, but when I timed it using the php function `time()`, it was apparent that this takes almost nothing time to complete, so I assumed it is a non-blocking call, and it would block, if I tried to access things in `$this->session->getPage()`, but that's not true either. I initially had a `($.active === 0)` condition as the second Argument of `wait()`, but that didn't work, so I removed the second Argument to isolate the Problem.
Is it necessary to use a `spin()` function as in [behat's docs](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/using_spin_functions.html), or is the `wait()` function enough. If `spin()` is necessary then what is `wait()` for?

#### Update

Having installed the [phantomjs driver for mink](https://github.com/jcalderonzumba/MinkPhantomJSDriver), and seeing that it works, I must conclude that the **Problem is with the Zombie Driver**.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHPUnit?

Comment: It's run in PHPUnit, I added that just in case...

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait() for a JS condition like:

```
wait(30000, "document.readyState === 'complete'")
```

Use spin for custom waits with functions as described in documentation.

Here are some other examples for ajax [how-to-make-behat-wait-for-an-ajax-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580813/how-to-make-behat-wait-for-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue and found this function on the internet, it works fine. [Reference](https://gist.github.com/jbouzekri/7f061771bf8d20b4f0d3).

```
/**
 * Wait
 *
 * @param integer $time  * @param string  $condition
 *
 * @throws BehaviorException If timeout is reached
 */
 public function wait($time = 10000, $condition = null){
    if (!$this->getSession()->getDriver() instanceof Selenium2Driver) {
        return;
    }
    $start = microtime(true);
    $end = $start + $time / 1000.0;
    if ($condition === null) {
        $defaultCondition = true;
        $conditions = [
            "document.readyState == 'complete'",           // Page is ready
            "typeof $ != 'undefined'",                     // jQuery is loaded
            "!$.active",                                   // No ajax request is active
            "$('#page').css('display') == 'block'",        // Page is displayed (no progress bar)
            "$('.loading-mask').css('display') == 'none'", // Page is not loading (no black mask loading page)
            "$('.jstree-loading').length == 0",            // Jstree has finished loading
        ];
        $condition = implode(' && ', $conditions);
    } else {
        $defaultCondition = false;
    }
    // Make sure the AJAX calls are fired up before checking the condition
    $this->getSession()->wait(100, false);
    $this->getSession()->wait($time, $condition);
    // Check if we reached the timeout unless the condition is false to explicitly wait the specified time
    if ($condition !== false && microtime(true) > $end) {
        if ($defaultCondition) {
            foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
                $result = $this->getSession()->evaluateScript($condition);
                if (!$result) {
                    throw new BehaviorException(
                        sprintf(
                            'Timeout of %d reached when checking on "%s"',
                            $time,
                            $condition
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new BehaviorException(sprintf('Timeout of %d reached when checking on %s', $time, $condition));
        }
    }
```